# Cannot put 2 div inside of one div horizontally

Tags: html, css

This is my JSFiddle - [code](https://jsfiddle.net/xh93uoxj/)

My problem is that I cannot put `form1` and `form2` inside `content` division.

I tried some solutions and didn't work:

1. `Float:left` for these 2 div
2. Use `position:fixed;` 
   not sure what goes wrong.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftbar">
    </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="form1">
            </div>
            <div class="form2">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="botbar">
    </div>
```

Code:

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;


}

.leftbar{
    width:10%;
    height:90%;
    background-color:rgba(0,153,255,0.4);
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
}

.botbar{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

.content{
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    position:fixed;
    background:black;
    left:10%;

}

.form1{
    width:45%:
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}

.form2{
    width:45%:
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xh93uoxj/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xh93uoxj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hi now replace to this**   `:` into this `;`

**as like this**

```
 width: 45%:
```

into this

```
width:45%;
```

in your `.form2` and  `.form1` css class

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftbar">
    </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="form1">
                hello2
            </div>
            <div class="form2">
                hello
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="botbar">
    </div>

    <style>
    .form1,.form2
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .form1
    {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        border:1px solid green;

    }
    .form2
    {
        width: 50%;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid green;
    }

    .content
    {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .content:after
    {
        clear: both;
        display: block;



    .form1,.form2
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .form1
    {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        border:1px solid green;
        
    }
    .form2
    {
        width: 50%;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid green;
    }

    .content
    {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .content:after
    {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        content: "";
    }
    
    </style>









----------
## 


----------

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="leftbar">
    </div>
    
     <div class="content">
            <div class="form1">
                hello2
            </div>
            <div class="form2">
                hello
            </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="botbar">
    </div>
```